# OnBackPressed() quits application

Tags: android, android-fragments

My `onBackPressed()` sends me out of my app. How can I avoid this? Either it should send me back to last shown fragment or just send me to a specific fragment.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }
    else{
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: add fragment to backstack or manage it manually by reloading fragment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,If you are using Fragment android.support.v4.app.Fragment.

```
 private boolean allowExit = false;
```

Then

```
  @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
     DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
         drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
     }
   else if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
        // handling fragment backbutton navigation
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    } else {
        if (allowExit) {

            super.onBackPressed();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.app_exit_message), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            allowExit = true;
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    allowExit = false;
                }
            }, 3000);
        }
    }
}
```

If you are using not support fragment you have to replace

```
  @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
     DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
         drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
     }
   else if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
        // handling fragment backbutton navigation
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    } else {
        if (allowExit) {

            super.onBackPressed();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.app_exit_message), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            allowExit = true;
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    allowExit = false;
                }
            }, 3000);
        }
    }
}
```

And add message to the string.xml

```
<string name="app_exit_message">Press again to exit</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code.
1. If your drawer is opened it will close the drawer.
2. If Any fragment is in backstack, it will navigate you to the previous fragment.
3. If No Fragment is in backstack, it will close the application.

```
        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
                drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            } else {
                oneStepBack();
            }
        }

        /**
         * function to go back to previous fragment
         */
        private void oneStepBack() {
            FragmentTransaction fts = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            showOutput("Back Stack Count>>>>>>>>>>" + fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount());
            if (fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() >= 2) {
                fragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate();
                fts.commit();
            } else {
                finish();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }
    else{

        write your code here what activity you want to open on back press   and remove below line 
        //super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

DrawerLayout should be initialised in onCreate() method ,so you are facing the problem.

For your reference check this , it may help you.
http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/